# How to read objects in Openstack Swift based on Object Metadata

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I know that we can store metadata with each object in Swift using `.addHeader("X-Object-Meta-{name}",value)` on the request builder.

How can I get a list of objects for with a particular metadata?

Basically I'm looking for a quick, efficient way of searching objects in `Openstack` Swift using the object Metadata.